# TF Object Detection API - Trouble running quantized network after freezing and quantizing my fine-tuned network

Tags: tensorflow

## TensorFlow Object Detection API

Using the TensorFlow Object Detection API to retrain MobileNet on my own DataSet. The issue occurs as I try to run my inference graph that has been both frozen and quantized.

### System:

- Ubuntu 16.04,
- TensorFlow 1.2 (from source, CPU only),
- Bazel 0.4.5

### Issue:

- Use provided frozen_graph.pb from model zoo.
- Quantize to 8-bit using
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph.
- Run inference

This works, however,

- Re-train and produce my own frozen_graph.pb using object_detection/export_inference_graph.py
- Quantize to 8-bit using bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph
- Run inference <-- Produces error

Does NOT work, and the error I'm getting during the attempt to run the graph is:

> File
>   "/home/unibap/TensorFlow/tensorflow-python2-sse4.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1298, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: The node
>   'Preprocessor/map/while/ResizeImage/ResizeBilinear/eightbit' has
>   inputs from different frames. The input
>   'Preprocessor/map/while/ResizeImage/size' is in frame
>   'Preprocessor/map/while/Preprocessor/map/while/'. The input
>   'Preprocessor/map/while/ResizeImage/ResizeBilinear_eightbit/Preprocessor/map/while/ResizeImage/ExpandDims/quantize'
>   is in frame ''.

Since I can quantize and run the provided frozen_graph.pb the issue has to be with the export tool? Which export tool was used to create the frozen_graph.pb that are in the model zoo? Or how was the export tool called?

PS:
Quote from comments in export_inference_graph.pb, assuring me that it should produce a frozen graph if checkpoint is provided.

"Optionally, one can freeze the graph by converting the weights in the provided
checkpoint as graph constants thereby eliminating the need to use a checkpoint
file during inference."

Best